# How to create a "placeholder" for DIV that act like textfield?

Tags: html, placeholder

Div don't have a placeholder attribute

```html
<div id="editable" contentEditable="true"></div>
```

I want `<Please your enter your Name>` to show in DIV when the User backspace the whole text in the DIV, or no text on inside, How can I do it?

Comment: can you explain more on how can user 'backspace a div'?

Comment: sorry my fault, forget to code it

Comment: javascript will be your friend in this situation!

Comment: can show me some example??

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What I find in other answers is that when using `:not(:focus)` pseudo class, I have to click again in order to get the blinking cursor and be able to type. Such issue doesn't happen if I click on an area other than the placeholder.

My workaround is simply removing `:not(:focus)`. Even though in this way the placeholder will still be there after I click on the editable div, I'm able to type no matter where in the div I click, and the placeholder disappears immediately after I type something.

BTW, I inspected YouTube's comment div implementation, seems they are doing the same thing, e.g. `#contenteditable-root.yt-formatted-string[aria-label].yt-formatted-string:empty:before`

```css
.editableDiv1,
.editableDiv2 {
  border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
  outline: none;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.editableDiv1[contentEditable="true"]:empty:not(:focus):before {
  content: attr(placeholder)
}

.editableDiv2[contentEditable="true"]:empty:before {
  content: attr(placeholder)
}
```

```html
<div class="editableDiv1" contentEditable=true placeholder="If you click on this placeholder, you have to click again in order to get the blinking cursor and type..."></div>

<div class="editableDiv2" contentEditable=true placeholder="Click on placeholder is fine, it'll disappear after you type something..."></div>
```

Answer (score 67):

Here is a pure CSS only solution:-

```
<div contentEditable=true data-ph="My Placeholder String"></div>
<style>
    [contentEditable=true]:empty:not(:focus):before{
        content:attr(data-ph)
    }
</style>
```

Here, we basically select all `contentEditable` `<divs>` that are empty & blurred. We then create a pseudo element before the CSS selection (the editable div) and fix our placeholder text (specified the `data-ph` attribute) as its content.
<s>If you are targeting old school CSS2 browsers, change all occurrences of `data-ph` to `title`</s>
Correction.......the `:empty` selector is not supported in IE version 8 and earlier.

Comment: Thans man, I never thought u could do smth like this with pure css. Awesome !

Comment: Unconstructive comment: This is beautiful! Great job!

Comment: how to keep placeholder even when the element is focused? without not(:focus) selector, the caret disappears or appears at wrong place.

Comment: @boh, to keep placeholder even when the element is focused, do this: [contentEditable=true]:empty:before { content: attr(data-ph) }

Comment: This won't work if there is any character or white-space between the opening and the closing `div` tags.

Comment: I found if I click on the placeholder content, then I have to click the div again in order to get the cursor, otherwise I won't be able to enter anything; no this issue when I click on the div other than the placeholder area. (tested on Chrome 83.0.4103.116)

Answer (score 8):

You can try this one !

html:

```
<div contentEditable=true data-text="Enter name here"></div>
```

css:

```
[contentEditable=true]:empty:not(:focus):before{
content:attr(data-text) }
```

[check it out (demo)](http://jsfiddle.net/hsp0kny7/1/)

Comment: how is that different from the first answer?

Answer (score -2):

**in HTML**

```
<div id="editable" contenteditable="true">
    <p>Please your enter your Name</p>
</div>
```

**in JavaScript**

```
jQuery.fn.selectText = function(){
    var doc = document;
    var element = this[0];
    console.log(this, element);
    if (doc.body.createTextRange) {
        var range = document.body.createTextRange();
        range.moveToElementText(element);
        range.select();
    } else if (window.getSelection) {
        var selection = window.getSelection();        
        var range = document.createRange();
        range.selectNodeContents(element);
        selection.removeAllRanges();
        selection.addRange(range);
    }
};

$("#editable").click(function() {
    $("#editable").selectText();
});
```

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/achudars/2Xpe6/)**